# How do I remove words from a List in a case-insensitive manner?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list called `words` containing words which may be in upper or lower case, or some combination of them. Then I have another list called `stopwords` which contains only lowercase words. Now I want to go through each word in `stopwords` and remove all instances of that word from `words` in a case-insensitive manner, but I don't know how to do this. Suggestions?

Example:

```
words = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'string']
stopwords = ['this', 'test']

for stopword in stopwords:
    if stopword in words:
        words.remove(stopword);

print words
```

The result shown is this: `['This', 'is', 'a', 'string']`

The correct return should have been this: `['is', 'a', 'string']`

Answer (score 9):

Make your word lowercase so you don't need to worry about casing:

```
words = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'string']
stopwords = {'this', 'test'}

print([i for i in words if i.lower() not in stopwords])
```

Outputs:

```
['is', 'a', 'string']
```

As an additional note, per @cricket_007 (and thanks to @chepner for the correction) comment, making stopwords a set would make it more performant. Notice the change to stopwords above making it a set instead of a list.

Comment: Would run better if stopwords were a `set`

Comment: You made `stopwords` a tuple, not a set. `{'this', 'test'}` in Python 2.7+, `set(['this', 'test'])` otherwise.

Comment: So sets run faster in this scenario? Is it worth the processing time to convert a long list/tuple (that will also be used elsewhere as a list/tuple) to a set for these "in" tests?

Comment: @Tom Yes, if your stopwords is a sequence of unique words, then you should use a set, definitely. Your lookup is improved. Check out the Complexity table: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity